# How to split an ordered array of durations in one-hour groups

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array with some durations (in seconds), I'd like to split that array into accumulated duration groups that not surpass 3600 seconds in **MATLAB**. The durations are in order.

```
Input:

             Duration(s) |   2010 1000 500 1030 80 2030 1090

With an:

                             ------------- ------------ ----

Accumulated duration (s) |       3510          3130     1090 

                             ------------- ------------ ----


                              1st group     2nd group   3rd 

Output:

            Groups index |    1    1    1    2   2  2    3
```

I've tried with some scripts, but these take so long, and I have to process a lot of data.

Comment: what output do you expect for `durations = [2010 1000 500 1030 80 2530 1090]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way using [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [**`cumsum`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
durations = [2010 1000 500 1030 80 2030 1090]
stepsize = 3600;

idx = sum(bsxfun(@ge, cumsum(durations), (0:stepsize:sum(durations)).'),1)
```

---

```
idx =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     3
```

---

The accumulated durations you can then get with:

```
accDuratiation = accumarray(idx(:),durations(:),[],@sum).'
```

---

```
accDuratiation =

        3510        3140        1090
```

---

### Explanation:

```
%// cumulative sum of all durations
csum = cumsum(durations);

%// thresholds
threshs = 0:stepsize:sum(durations);

%// comparison
comp = bsxfun(@ge, csum(:).',threshs(:)) %'

comp =

 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1


%// get index
idx = sum(comp,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you close . . .

```
durs = [2010 1000 500 1030 80 2030 1090];
cums = cumsum(durs);
t = 3600;

idx = zeros(size(durs));
while ~all(idx)    
    idx = idx + (cums <= t);
    cums = cums - max(cums(cums <= t));
end
```

You can then get the output into your preferred format with a simple . .

```
idx = -(idx-max(idx)-1)
```

Comment: Nice use of cumsum, but I think both `<` signs should be `<=`.

Comment: @JeffIrwin well spotted

Answer (score 0):

and just in case you don't have enough, yet another way to do it:

```
durations = [2010 1000 500 1030 80 2030 1090] ;
stepsize = 3600;

cs = cumsum(durations) ;
idxbeg = [1 find(sign([1 diff(mod(cs,stepsize))])==-1)] ; %// first index of each group
idxend = [idxbeg(2:end)-1 numel(d)] ;      %// last index of each group

groupDuration = [cs(idxend(1)) diff(cs(idxend))]

groupIndex = cell2mat( arrayfun(@(x,y) repmat(x,1,y), 1:numel(idxbeg) , idxend-idxbeg+1 , 'uni',0) )

groupDuration =
        3510        3140        1090
groupIndex =
     1     1     1     2     2     2     3
```

*<sub>although if you ask me I find the `bsxfun` solution more elegant</sub>*